# Magento 2: Add a custom link in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, checkout-page

I want to add a link (`Continue Shopping`) that takes me to the homepage, on the checkout step `myshop.com/checkout` refer to image attached.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: I will let you know once i tested it. Thanks alot for your prompt response

Comment: i tried exactly what you told but its not working for me. I have also cleaned the cache and checked it, but its still not working, even i tried to add custom link in the core module in,
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` in your **custom theme**

> app/design/frontend/Test/test/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

**OR** If you have **custom module** Override `shipping.html` at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Now add custom link before `<div class="actions-toolbar">` like this

```
<div class="custom-link">
    <a href="your-link">Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
    <div class="primary">
        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now deploy static files by `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
and flush cache

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: I overridden this,
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
with this,
app/design/frontend/sps/design/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html but link is still not showing up?

Comment: You need to deploy static file by `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to see changes.

Comment: Overriding using a plugin isn't gonna work unless you add a requirejs-config.js-file to /Vendor/Module/view/frontend containing the following:

`var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping'
        }
    }
};`

Comment: @DaanvandenBergh Yes, If you override html file with custom module then you must need requirejs-config to override html files

Comment: @PrincePatel, I need to form custom url dynamically, i mean some php javascript variable value need to append. How that can be done?

Comment: @jafarpinjar you need to override shipping template component `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping`

Answer (score 3):

Override `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` and add a link before the button.

```
    <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">

      <!-- add link here -->

      <div class="primary">
        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
        </button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I have overridden the file you mentioned in mytheme, and i have also tried adding anchor tag in the core file you mentioned. But in both cases my checkout page stucks and keeps on loading. There might be something we are missing.

Comment: It should work. Just make sure you have overridden properly

Comment: Same goes here as my earlier comment. This isn't gonna work unless you add a requirejs-config.js-file to /Vendor/Module/view/frontend containing the following: `var config = { map: { '*': { 'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'Vendor_Module/template/shipping' } } };`